# Copying items from one list in one site to another in another site?

Tags: 2007, development, object-model

I have a class that I've been working on to allow me to move items in SharePoint, whilst retaining meta data. The class is as follows:

```
public class Lists
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Access and modify items in SharePoint lists within the same site
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="siteURL"></param>
        /// <param name="sourceList"></param>
        /// <param name="destinationList"></param>
        /// <param name="retainMeta"></param>
        public static void MoveListItems(string siteURL, string sourceList, string destinationList, bool retainMeta)
        {
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Opening site: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), siteURL);

            using (var site = new SPSite(siteURL))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Opened site: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), siteURL);

                using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Web Relative URL is: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), web.ServerRelativeUrl);

                    try
                    {
                        // Get your source and destination libraries
                        var source = web.GetList(web.ServerRelativeUrl + sourceList);
                        var destination = web.GetList(web.ServerRelativeUrl + destinationList);

                        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Source set to: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), source);
                        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Destination set to: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), destination);

                        // Get the collection of items to move, use source.GetItems(SPQuery) if you want a subset
                        SPListItemCollection items = source.Items;

                        // Get the root folder of the destination we'll use this to add the files
                        SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder(destination.RootFolder.Url);

                        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Moving {1} files from {2} to {3} - please wait...", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(),
                                          items.Count, source, destination);

                        var fileCount = 0;
                        // Now to move the files and the metadata
                        foreach (SPListItem item in items)
                        {
                            //Get the file associated with the item
                            SPFile file = item.File;

                            // Create a new file in the destination library with the same properties
                            SPFile newFile = folder.Files.Add(folder.Url + "/" + file.Name, file.OpenBinary(), file.Properties, true);

                            // Optionally copy across the created/modified metadata                        
                            if (retainMeta)
                            {
                                SPListItem newItem = newFile.Item;
                                WriteFileMetaData(item, newItem);
                            }

                            // Delete the original version of the file
                            // todo: make local backup before deleting?
                            file.Delete();

                            fileCount++;
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Completed moving {1} files to {2}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), fileCount,
                                          destination);

                    }
                    catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(
                            "[{0}] Unable to set a location. Please check that paths for source and destination libraries are correct and relative to the site collection.",
                            DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());

                        throw;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Exception: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), ex);

                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Access and modify items in SharePoint lists in differing sites
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sourceSiteURL"></param>
        /// <param name="sourceList"></param>
        /// <param name="destinationSiteURL"></param>
        /// <param name="destinationList"></param>
        /// <param name="retainMeta"></param>
        public static void MoveListItemsSiteToSite(string sourceSiteURL, string sourceList, string destinationSiteURL,
                                                   string destinationList, bool retainMeta)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Opening Source site: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), sourceSiteURL);

            using (var sourceSite = new SPSite(sourceSiteURL))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Opened Source site: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), sourceSiteURL);

                using (var sourceWeb = sourceSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Source Web Relative URL is: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), sourceWeb.ServerRelativeUrl);

                    try
                    {
                        // Get your source library
                        var source = sourceWeb.GetList(sourceWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + sourceList);
                        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Source set to: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), source);

                        // Get the collection of items to move, use source.GetItems(SPQuery) if you want a subset
                        SPListItemCollection items = source.Items;

                        var fileCount = 0;

                        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Opening Destination site: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), destinationSiteURL);

                        using (var destSite = new SPSite(destinationSiteURL))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Opened Destination site: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), destSite);

                            using (var destinationWeb = destSite.OpenWeb())
                            {

                                Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Destination Web Relative URL is: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(),
                                                  destinationWeb.ServerRelativeUrl);

                                // get destination library
                                var destination = destinationWeb.GetList(destinationWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + destinationList);
                                Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Destination set to: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), destination);

                                // Get the root folder of the destination we'll use this to add the files
                                SPFolder destinationFolder = destinationWeb.GetFolder(destination.RootFolder.Url);


                                Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Moving {1} files from {2} to {3} - please wait...", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(),
                                                  items.Count, source, destination);


                                // Now to move the files and the metadata
                                foreach (SPListItem item in items)
                                {
                                    //Get the file associated with the item
                                    SPFile file = item.File;

                                    // Create a new file in the destination library with the same properties
                                    SPFile newFile = destinationFolder.Files.Add(destinationFolder.Url + "/" + file.Name, file.OpenBinary(),
                                                                                 file.Properties, true);

                                    // Optionally copy across the created/modified metadata                        
                                    if (retainMeta)
                                    {
                                        SPListItem newItem = newFile.Item;
                                        WriteFileMetaData(item, newItem);
                                    }

                                    // Delete the original version of the file
                                    // todo: make local backup before deleting?
                                    file.Delete();

                                    fileCount++;
                                }

                                Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Completed moving {1} files to {2}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), fileCount,
                                                  destination);
                            }

                        }


                    }
                    catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(
                            "[{0}] Unable to set a location. Please check that paths for source and destination libraries are correct and relative to the site collection.",
                            DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());

                        throw;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Exception: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), ex);

                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Overwrite existing meta data for a file with meta data from another file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sourceItem">Source file to take meta data from</param>
        /// <param name="destinationItem">Destination file to write meta data to</param>
        public static void WriteFileMetaData(SPListItem sourceItem, SPListItem destinationItem)
            // overwrites a list items meta data with meta data from another file
        {
            //todo: change to write individual items instead of using source item

            destinationItem["Editor"] = sourceItem["Editor"];
            destinationItem["Modified"] = sourceItem["Modified"];
            destinationItem["Modified By"] = sourceItem["Modified By"];
            destinationItem["Author"] = sourceItem["Author"];
            destinationItem["Created"] = sourceItem["Created"];
            destinationItem["Created By"] = sourceItem["Created By"];

            // UpdateOverwriteVersion() will preserve the metadata added above. 
            destinationItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
        }
    }
```

The method above `MoveListItems` works perfectly fine. Items move, meta data is retained and people are partying in the streets. Unfortunately the same cannot be said of `MoveListItemsSiteToSite`. With this method no error is thrown but no items are copied also. I can't figure out why and the output I'm being given shows that I'm feeding the right data in.

If you'd prefer another example the below is a program you can copy into any solution. I'm basically trying to change this to allow items to be copied from one site to another but I'm having no success... help?

```
public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string connectionString = @"http://Mdev/re/ad/wf";

            Console.WriteLine("## M Archiver started at: {0} ##", DateTime.Now);

            var fileCount=0;

            // Declare and initialize the new site
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Opening site: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), connectionString);
            using (var site = new SPSite(connectionString))
            {
                // open the site
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {


                    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Opened site: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), web);
                    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Web Relative URL is: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), web.ServerRelativeUrl);

                    try
                    {
                        // Get your source and destination libraries
                        var source = web.GetList(web.ServerRelativeUrl + @"/Approval%20History%20%20Sales1");
                        var destination = web.GetList(web.ServerRelativeUrl + @"/Approval%20History%20%20Sales");

                        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Source set to: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), source);
                        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Destination set to: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), destination);

                        // Get the collection of items to move, use source.GetItems(SPQuery) if you want a subset
                        SPListItemCollection items = source.Items;

                        // Get the root folder of the destination we'll use this to add the files
                        SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder(destination.RootFolder.Url);

                        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Moving {1} files from {2} to {3} - please wait...", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(),
                                          items.Count, source, destination);

                        // Now to move the files and the metadata
                        foreach (SPListItem item in items)
                        {
                            //Get the file associated with the item
                            SPFile file = item.File;

                            // Create a new file in the destination library with the same properties
                            SPFile newFile = folder.Files.Add(folder.Url + "/" + file.Name, file.OpenBinary(), file.Properties, true);

                            // Optionally copy across the created/modified metadata                        
                            SPListItem newItem = newFile.Item;
                            newItem["Editor"] = item["Editor"];
                            newItem["Modified"] = item["Modified"];
                            newItem["Modified By"] = item["Modified By"];
                            newItem["Author"] = item["Author"];
                            newItem["Created"] = item["Created"];
                            newItem["Created By"] = item["Created By"];

                            // UpdateOverwriteVersion() will preserve the metadata added above. 
                            newItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion();

                            // Delete the original version of the file
                            // todo: make local backup before deleting?
                            file.Delete();
                            fileCount++;
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Completed moving {1} files to {2}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), fileCount,
                                          destination);
                    }
                    catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(
                            "[{0}] Unable to set a location. Please check that paths for source and destination libraries are correct and relative to the site collection.",
                            DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        web.Dispose();
                        site.Dispose();
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}] All operations complete, exiting...", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you mean "site" you actually mean SPSite (site collection) or SPWeb (sub-site)? Tried this http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.ch/2009/11/how-to-copy-files-across-site.html

Comment: The intent is to copy from a library contained in one site collection to one in another site collection

Comment: then go ahead with the example, and let us know if it helped!

Comment: @C.Marius Now resolved - thank-you for your help. Feel free to post as an answer if you'd like some karma for it :)

Comment: I went through various links over the Internet and found the below link very helpful in copying list item from one SP site to list in another SP site http://www.fivenumber.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/Copy%20list%20items%20from%20one%20to%20another%20programmatically.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy files from one site collection to another a very good example is explained in this article  http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.ch/2009/11/how-to-copy-files-across-site.html